# UnsatisfiedLinkError using JavaCV maven dependency in Gradle on Android

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, javacv, javacpp

I am getting this error when trying to call the `start()` method of an instance of `FFmpegFrameGrabber` :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:390)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:358)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext.<clinit>(avformat.java:2539)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:383)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:377)
```

These are the dependencies I am referring to per the READMES for the projects [javacpp](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) and [javacv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv):

```
compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacpp', version: '1.0'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.0'
```

I did not add any .so files to the project, but I was expecting those to come with the dependencies. When I tried adding them previously I started getting gradle errors for duplicate files so I assume that they come with the dependencies.

I think what is happening is that it can't load the .so files for whatever reason, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

I have tried setting the `systemProperty` for dependencies mentioned in the GitHub READMEs like so:

```
task execute(type: JavaExec) {
    systemProperty "platform.dependencies", true
}
```

It doesn't help as written.

**Why is this error seen and what can be done to handle it?**

Any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. The overall goal is to use the FFmpegFrameGrabber to crop video the user has taken with their device. I am open to all solutions.

Comment: FYI, it's probably easier to just add the platform specific artifacts manually. I'm not sure how we're supposed to set system properties through Android Studio.